# How to validate header in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I want to add a middleware to check the header values. if the expected do not present in the header then I want throw an error on API response. Following code is throwing error and I can see it in the console but I want to send this error to the user.

```
const server = new Server({
        host: config.get('host'),
        port: config.get('port' )
    });

    await server.register(require('@hapi/inert')); // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

    server.register({
        plugin: AuthService
    })

    server.route(
        // mapping route paths with context path
        routes.map((datum) => {
            return {
                ...datum,
                path: `${config.get('basePath')}${datum.path}`
            };
        })
    );
```

**plugin**

```
import { notFound } from '@hapi/boom';

export const AuthService = {
    name: 'authService',
    version: '1.0.0',
    register: async function (server: any, options: any) {
        throw notFound(`Unauthorized user not found`);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you are thinking it the express way too much. You should look at the authentication part of Hapi.

You can create a custom strategy and return an error if the header is not present.

Also, you can check how to use a `Joi.schema()` for all your routes.